# Sharing an app with .ipa file and make push notifications to work

Tags: ios

If I share an ipa file to test my iOS app on colleague devices, are push notifications going to work ?

Do I need to register any new colleague profile / submit the devices on which the app is going to be installed ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sign the app with the same certificate created when you enabled Push Notifications for the app. When the testing user installs that app and accepts push notifications for this app, they will receive them, simple enough.

Comment: The app is currently signed with the certificate for push notifications, since it is perfectly working on 2 of my devices. If I've understood well, you are saying that I can just share the app and the certificates are stored in it, so no further steps are required. Could you confirm it ?